# Transform a table using dplyr to be multiple columns with specific rule

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Okay so I have a table that looks...messy.

```
  Name  Location  Team    Virtue
  Hank       ABQ     A     Alpha
 Flynn       ABQ     B     Alpha
                            Beta
 Marie       JFK     X     Gamma

                            Beta 
Skylar       ABQ     B     Alpha
                            Beta
Walter       LAX     D     Gamma
 Gomie       ATL     A     Alpha

                            Beta

                           Gamma
  Saul       JFK     X      Beta
```

Here you see that `Virtue` can only ever be one of three values: 'Alpha', 'Beta', or 'Gamma'.

The goal is I want to create a new column to represent each of these values, denoted by 0 or 1. There are several articles online on how to do this however I need to group all Virtues based on the previous Name. Name is the row seperator so to speak. The final outcome should be:

```
  Name  Location  Team     Alpha  Beta Gamma
  Hank       ABQ     A         1     0     0
 Flynn       ABQ     B         1     1     0
 Marie       JFK     X         0     1     1
Skylar       ABQ     B         1     1     0
Walter       LAX     D         0     0     1
 Gomie       ATL     A         1     1     1
  Saul       JFK     X         0     1     0
```

Comment: Hi John. Could you please share your dataset in a reproducible format using `dput()`? As is one can only guess whether the blank spots in your dataset are missings or empty strings or ... But you could try `dat %>% tidyr::fill(Name, Location, Team) %>% mutate(value = 1) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Virtue, values_from = value, values_fill = 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your data

```
class(df)
[1] "data.frame"

df
     Name Location Team Virtue
1    Hank      ABQ    A  Alpha
2   Flynn      ABQ    B  Alpha
3                         Beta
4   Marie      JFK    X  Gamma
5                             
6                         Beta
7  Skylar      ABQ    B  Alpha
8                         Beta
9  Walter      LAX    D  Gamma
10  Gomie      ATL    A  Alpha
11                            
12                        Beta
13                            
14                       Gamma
15   Saul      JFK    X   Beta
```

- First filter completely empty rows
- Then replace empty strings with `NA`
- Fill the rows with previous data
- Finally `pivot_wider` *Virtue* and replace the strings with the results of the given function

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ .x != "")) %>% 
  mutate(replace(., . == "", NA)) %>% 
  fill(everything()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Virtue, 
              values_from = Virtue, 
              values_fn = ~ +(.x %in% unique(df$Virtue)), 
              values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 7 × 6
  Name   Location Team  Alpha  Beta Gamma
  <chr>  <chr>    <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 Hank   ABQ      A         1     0     0
2 Flynn  ABQ      B         1     1     0
3 Marie  JFK      X         0     1     1
4 Skylar ABQ      B         1     1     0
5 Walter LAX      D         0     0     1
6 Gomie  ATL      A         1     1     1
7 Saul   JFK      X         0     1     0
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Hank", "Flynn", "", "Marie", "", "", 
"Skylar", "", "Walter", "Gomie", "", "", "", "", "Saul"), Location = c("ABQ", 
"ABQ", "", "JFK", "", "", "ABQ", "", "LAX", "ATL", "", "", "", 
"", "JFK"), Team = c("A", "B", "", "X", "", "", "B", "", "D", 
"A", "", "", "", "", "X"), Virtue = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Beta", 
"Gamma", "", "Beta", "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Alpha", "", "Beta", 
"", "Gamma", "Beta")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```